# calculation of limits of char without using macro definitions

Tags: c, casting, bitwise-operators

I was trying to calculate the limits of type char using the following expression.

```
(char)(~(unsigned char)0 >> 1)
```

I expected this to be equal to 127 but answer is -1.

Then I replaced this expression.

```
~(unsigned char)0
```

by

```
(unsigned char)~0
```

This one is giving the correct answer
So how are these two different

Comment: You're casting `255` to a `char`, which is `signed`, hence `-1`.

Comment: @Fiddling Bits : But that would mean that complementation takes place after the right shift operation. Both the type cast and complementation have same precedence.

Comment: Misread.  Ignore my comment.

Comment: Just use `127`.  Formula used is non-portable anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `(char)((unsigned char)~0 >> 1)` is 127 is obvious - You have 0xFFFFFFFF, cast it to unsigned char, you get 0xFF, shift by one and you have 0x7F or 127.

The weird thing is why the first one is wrong: You cast a zero into unsigned char. Then you complement that. But the operator `~` actually promotes it's operand:

> The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

(n1570 section 6.5.3.3)

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions

(n1570 section 6.3.1.1)

Since an `int` can store all the values of an `unsigned char`, the result is an int. Which you shift by one, and then cast, resulting in -1